# Move insertion point to the beginning of the blank line between paragraphs MS Word

Tags: regex, ms-word, autohotkey

I often need to translate a document in MS Word and I do it paragraph by paragraph, the translation text follows each individual paragraph of the original text. What I need is a keyboard shortcut to move the insertion point to the blank space after the following paragraph I need to translate, i.e to move the cursor from the end of the red colored text in the picture to the blank space after the following paragraph ending with "..and call it a day"

[image]

Ctrl+Down Arrow shortcut in Word places the insertion point at the beginning of every following paragraph, while I need it placed at the beginning of the blank line above it so I can immediately start typing.

I am looking for a Word shortcut key, regex expression or an autohotkey script that could perform this task, it would come handy to me in doing translation in MS Word.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: For me, pressing `CTRL+DOWN` once jumps to the next blank line after the paragraph, a second press jumps to the beginning of the following paragraph, and a third press jumps to the blank line after the following paragraph. So the way I see it, you simply have to press `CTRL+DOWN` three times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer MCL! Normally I get text that contains only a paragraph break between paragraphs. CTRL-DOWN would work for me if the paragraphs are separated by two paragraph breaks, and they are normally not in documents I get to translate. I'm not much versed in MS Word and I'm not sure how you create line break in it.

Comment: Although I can't reproduce those paragraph breaks off the bat, I think [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/321809/216982) can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you MCL! I was thinking of doing it as suggested in the article you linked to but was looking for a quicker solution. I'd be happy with a shortcut that places cursor at the end of the following paragraph, but it seems that there is no such shortcut. It is strange that Word has a keyboard shortcuts for moving cursor position a word back or forward, to the end of the line or the beginning of the next paragraph, line up or down etc. but no one to place it at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: Well, what if you jump to the start of a paragraph and then one to the left (`CTRL+DOWN LEFT`)?

Comment: I'll do that MCL, thank you! I'll create an autohotkey script to make it work in one keyboard stroke.

Comment: Great. Please post it here as answer and accept it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

On MCL's suggestion I've created a simple Autohotkey script to solve the problem, combining Word keyboard shortcuts into one. I also added a code from another script which sets dark red color of the text which is being typed into the original document to make the contrast with the default text color of the original. This is a convenient option for translators which also allows saving only the translated text by using Find function in Word, and removes the need for any further editing of the translated document. Here's the script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class OpusApp
^2::
   Send ^{Down}
   Send ^{Down}
   Send ^{Left}
   Send {Enter}
{
oWord := ComObjActive("Word.Application") ; MS Word object
wdColorDarkRed = 128
oWord.Selection.Font.Color := wdColorDarkRed
}
return
```

Comment: `#IfWinActive ahk_class OpusApp` will have no effect here. Either put `#IfWinActive` on top of the hotkey label, or use the `IfWinActive` **condition** and the `Send`s inside a code block. I recommend the first alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the correction MCL, I've added a code which automatically changes the color of the text that is being typed in. Works fine for me.